# awscli post installation issue: Errno 2 - No such file or directory

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cli

I used a windows installer to install AWS CLI.

The version being used is - aws-cli/1.11.160 Python/2.7.9 Windows/8 botocore/1.7.18

With this, I am using Docker community edition - version 17.06.2-ce-win27(13194)

While running this command and trying to log into ECR, I am facing Errno 2 - no such file or directory :- 
Command: aws ecr get-login --no-include-email --region us-east-1

Keys are correctly configured.

Any ideas would be really appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This worked for me:

copy "c:\Program Files\Amazon\AWSCLI\botocore\vendored\requests\cacert.pem" "c:\Program Files\Amazon\AWSCLI\certifi"

Source: https://github.com/aws/aws-cli/issues/2855#issuecomment-332454762

Comment: This worked for me. Windows 10, AWS command line tools and S3